# Assigning row number after sorting

Tags: oracle, rownum

After sorting, how to assign row number to my code?

I have used ROWNUM, but result was not ordered `4,3,2,1,8,7,5,6` as below.

```
ROWNUM C0   M     SS 
------ --- ----- -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  4    a   ace    11                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  3    a   abe     7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  2    a   abd     3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  1    a   a__    21                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  8    b   ace    11                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  7    b   abe     7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  6    b   abd     3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  5    b   a__    21
```

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE T4 (
C0 VARCHAR2(10),
C1 VARCHAR2(10),
C2 NUMBER
);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','abd',1);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','abd',2);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','abe',3);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','abe',4);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','ace',5);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('a','ace',6);

INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','abd',1);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','abd',2);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','abe',3);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','abe',4);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','ace',5);
INSERT INTO T4  VALUES ('b','ace',6);



SELECT ROWNUM,rr.C0,rr.M, rr.ss -- How to modify to get 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,..
FROM
(
SELECT C0,C1 M, SUM(C2) ss FROM T4  GROUP BY C0, C1
UNION
SELECT C0,SUBSTR(C1,1,1)||'__'  , SUM(C2) ss FROM T4  GROUP BY C0,SUBSTR(C1,1,1)) rr
ORDER BY rr.C0,rr.M DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Move rownum outside query:

```
select rownum, r.* from (
... your query with order by
) r
```